# Stop SQLite browsers from accessing the database

Tags: sqlite

Our application uses a SQLite database for storing records, and there's a process 'dbd' that manages the database.

The application also provides a tool to examine the records in the said database.

Is there a way to ensure that the database is accessible only to the process and the tool mentioned above and is inaccessible to SQLite browsers and other utilities?

Thanks!

Comment: As far I remember, SQLite database is a single file with all the information, using this premise I can imagine that you can control the access rights of the file assigning the rights of write/read to a "technical user" and run the process that you want to access that database with that technical user so proceeses that runs with a different user will throw an error that they cannot access to the file.

Answer (score 2):

Basically the database is a file (2 if you include the journal or 3 if you use WAL), so you could protect it by restricting access to the file(s). Another alternative, could be to encrypt the database, and thus protect that data itself using [SEE - SQlite Encryption Extension](https://www.sqlite.org/see/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki).

Comment: Is there a way to password protect the database whereby anyone, but the desired entity, trying to access the database will be denied access?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look here:

http://www.iqx7.com/products/sqlite-encryption

This is a commercial C language code encryption module. It works with PHP as well.